# Spherical Harmonics Sum Identity

Tags: summation, physics, mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

I'm taking a course in Quantum Mechanics and this problem is causing me some struggles. Can someone help me prove this identity?

$$\sum_{m = -l}^l m^2 |Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)|^2 = \frac{l(l+1)(2l+1)}{8\pi}\sin^2(\theta)$$

I had the idea to use addition theorem for the same $\theta$ and $\phi$ given by
$$\sum_{m = -l}^l |Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)|^2  = \frac{(2l+1)}{4\pi}$$
Also I tried to use some recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials and induction on $l$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You're more likely to get help if you provide some context in your question, like where you encountered this problem, any attempts you've already made to solve it, or anything you know that might be helpful (like properties of spherical harmonics, in this case).

Comment: What is $Y_m^l$? What is $sen$?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is sin*